# Can I sum values in 2 different table fields and sort on that value via Rails / Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a DuesPayment and a Donation model. I want to list members in descending order by total of dues + donations. Is this something active record can do exclusively or will I have to make some addition and sorting code in the app?

The db is Postgres

Answer (score 2):

You can make this happen using the select, where and order clause.  Suppose we had a table with this schema:

```
  create_table "leaders", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "leaderable_id"
    t.string   "leaderable_type"
    t.integer  "county_id"
    t.integer  "us_state_id"
    t.integer  "recruits"
    t.integer  "hours"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.datetime "last_run_dt"
  end
```

If you want to order the results you would run a query like this:

```
Leader.select("(hours + recruits) as hr").order("hr")
```

If you want to select records based on the sum then you can ran a query like this:

```
Leader.select("(hours + recruits) as hr").where("(hours +recruits) > 1100")
```

You can access the result like:

```
Leader.select("(hours + recruits) as hr").order("hr").first.hr
```